# Can ANTLR4 generate separate Cpp files for a parser?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm working on a parser that's getting a complex/large file in C++. Since each rule gets its own class created, for rules that are not dependent on each other I was wondering if there's a way to instruct the antlr tool to generate the C++ code in separate .cpp files.

Regards,
JZ

Comment: You could, but you'd need to alter the templates for the Cpp target, and create a new complete.jar Antlr Tool file.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought about it that way, thanks!, I'll take a look at the source for the tool.

Comment: I had to add a bunch of code but I was able to get what I needed, thanks!

Comment: If you waded through the [Antlr4 templates for code generation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/Cpp), you are very brave!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's a way to instruct the antlr tool to generate the C++ code in separate .cpp files

No, there is no such thing possible out of the box.